# Why doesn't my text filter strip out the tags I don't want?

Tags: 7, input-formats

I thought I understood text filters, but it appears I don't.

I am using a filter on my node's "body" field that is supposed to restrict tags. I have entered the allowed HTML tags as

`<em> <strong> <cite> <blockquote> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd> <br>`

Yet in my WYSIWYG editor I can switch to source view and save text that includes  (or worse, ) tags.

Why aren't these tags stripped out when the node is saved?

Comment: Are you using CKeditor?

Comment: Yes, CKEditor. Version 4.4.7 I believe.

Comment: check your [/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ewjvd.jpg) and make sure those tags are in the allowed tags. (Assuming you are using Filtered HTML as your format)

Comment: The string of tags in my question above is the one for my text filter, copied and pasted from the text filter config. I've been able to add "script", "img", and "a" tags with no issues, even though they should be stripped out when saving the node (if I understand the text filtering system correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've found my own answer. The problem *was* with my understanding of how text filters work. Text is saved into the database with no changes, and filters are only applied when the text is output.

When using Entity Metadata Wrappers, as I am, when you get $wrapper->body->value(), it gives you an array with several elements. One is the "value", which is the raw, unfiltered text. Another is the "safe_value", which has had filters applied.

So in my case I needed to use the "safe_value" when displaying the text. Makes sense once you understand it!